# Canvas splitting image into rgba components

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to split a black and white image into its RGB components and offset each layer setting it to overlay. The idea is to have a hero image slightly out of register and randomly move it slightly.

I am wondering if this is in fact the correct way to approach this.

I tend to crash the browser if I dare add a console log in the function to see where I am going wrong.

Has anyone done this kind of manipulation in the browser and is it viable?

https://github.com/Julieslv/image-shift/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 7):

### Splitting image into RGBA channels

First note that you can not separate the channels from an image. You can only set the unwanted channels to zero. However setting the alpha channel to zero will automatically zero all channels. Thus you must keep the alpha channel.

#### Copy image

To copy an image create a second canvas and draw the original image onto it.

The following function will do that

```
function copyToCanvas(image) {
    const can = document.createElement("canvas");
    can.width = image.naturalWidth || image.width;
    can.height = image.naturalHeight || image.height;
    can.ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    can.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    return can;
}
```

#### Removing channel data

Two remove the unwanted channel data from a image copied by the previous method requires two steps.

1. Use composite operation `"multiply"` to remove unwanted channel data.
2. The above step will set the alpha channel to 255. To put the alpha back you use the composite operation `"destination-in"` and draw the original image over the new image.

The following function will copy the image, remove unwanted channel data and keep the alpha channel intact.

```
const channels = {
   red: "#F00",
   green: "#0F0",
   blue: "#00F",
};

function getChannel(channelName, image) {
    const copy = copyToCanvas(image);
    const ctx = copy.ctx;
    ctx.fillStyle = channels[channelName];
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    return copy;
}
```

#### Getting RGB channels

As the alpha channel is maintained you need only separate out red green and blue channels.

Using the previous function the following will create an object the holds the original image and the 3 channels

```
 function seperateRGB(image) {
     return {
         red: getChannel("red", image),
         green: getChannel("green", image),
         blue: getChannel("blue", image),
     };
 }
```

#### Recombining channels

Now that the channels have been separated you can recombine channels by first making a new canvas the same size as the original image plus any offsets you are adding as you recombine the image (if you are not adding back alpha).

```
function createCanvas(w, h) {
    const can = document.createElement("canvas");
    can.width = w;
    can.height = h;
    can.ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    return can;
}
```

Then draw the first channel (can be any of the 3) onto the new canvas. Then draw the other two channels using the composite operation `"lighter"`. Then restore alpha using composite operation `"destination-in"`

```
const RGB = seperateRGB(image);
const recombined = createCanvas(RGB.red.width, RGB.red.height);
const ctx = recombined.ctx;

ctx.drawImage(RGB.red, -2, -2);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
ctx.drawImage(RGB.green, 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(RGB.blue, 2, 2);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

### All done

The canvas element `recombined` holds the recombined image with the green and blue channels offset by 2 pixels and the original alpha restored.

**Note** that you do not need to restore the alpha. Restoring the alpha if some channels are offset will remove some of the non overlapping pixels.

Comment: WOW! Thanks for such a robust answer... You make it look so easy. I don't think i would have come up with that on my own. Wasn't quite what I was after, but certainly gave me something to work with. The copies are still in greyscale, but I am sure I can figure it out from what I did before. Again thanks so much.

Comment: Great solution, Blindman67! There is a typo in `getChannel`: globalComposietOperation → globalCompositeOperation.